# Is it expected that firejail allows R/W outside of the sandbox without "--overlay" flag?

Tags: linux, ubuntu-16.04, sandbox, firejail

Just installed [firejail](https://firejail.wordpress.com/) on Ubuntu 16.04 (version *0.9.38*) and according to this **linux-magazine** [article](http://www.linux-magazine.com/Issues/2015/173/Firejail), by default it should make *R/O* the entire filesystem:

> The programs in the sandbox have only read access to all directories and are thus unable to manipulate any important files.

Now, I tried the following on my computer:

1. `touch /disk5/test.txt`
2. `firejail gvim /disk5/test.txt`
3. modify the file and save it (`wq!`)
4. `cat /disk5/test.txt`
5. **does display changes done by** gvim **during** firejail **session!**

Is this expected behaviour? Wasn't *firejail* supposed to protect me from overwriting the original file? What have I done wrong?
Please note that `/disk5` is mounted in the root filesystem, outside of my `/home`.

Raised a bug on [github](https://github.com/netblue30/firejail/issues/970)

Comment: You forgot to append the `--private` flag to Firejail.  
True, the `man` page states `Only /home and /tmp are writable.  
  
Are you sure you are not trying this under your Home? Or a folder/disk mounted under your Home or something like that? Checking the man page is also useful, there are tons of various options for Firejail. `man firejail` and see which other arguments you might need.

Comment: @Shiki `/disk5/...` is mounted outside of my home, that's why I'm very surprised...

Answer (score 4):

`firejail` is not a magical tool that makes everything right. It's a security tool that lets *you* define your own rules on how to deal with stuff. For example, these arguments:

```
firejail --noprofile
```

Will not give any protection at all. Because you didn't specify any constraints, and firejail is permissive by default. In order to make some dirs read-only, you should write it explicitely. Something like:

```
firejail --noprofile --read-only=/ --read-only=~ --read-only=/tmp
```

(I wrote `/`, `~` and `/tmp` separately because firejail has a somewhat surprising behaviour of sorting your directives by some not-so-trivial rules and making its own `~` mounts in the middle.)

Also, without any `--caps.drop=all` arguments, `--seccomp` and such your programs won't be secure anyway. Because the process could communicate with other processes via unix sockets, abstract sockets etc, exploiting their bugs. If you want a relatively OK "jail", add at least seccomp, caps.drop=all, and nonewprivs directives.

EDIT: the quote you mentioned is probably just wrong. (Or so I think.) It's more complex than just "everything is read-only".

Comment: from the `man` page under `--nonewprivs`: "This option is enabled by default if seccomp filter is activated."

Comment: @user598527 please feel free to make any edits you wish. I'm not using firejail for a number of years already, having migrated to bubblewrap. I don't really remember anymore.

Answer (score -3):

Why would you keep your programs in a non-standard Unix directory such as /disk5? You are definitely asking for trouble. Store your executables in the regular places, such as /bin, /usr/bin. /usr/local/bin, or even /opt. Make sure all your executables are owned by root and regular users don't have write access to them. Linux is a Unix system, just follow the Unix rules and you'll be safe.

Comment: I can't really, especially if those are 3rd party software such as games from _steam_, my own compiled executables that I'm developing/building, etc etc... I wouldn't and couldn't definitely install those under the system bin paths...